# How to decode MIME filename sent from iPhone (python decode_header)

Tags: python, email, mime, email-attachments

I have application that receives images from mobile phones sent via email.
Everything worked fine till I received image from iPhone, I never seen this type of encoding (it's not MIME) so can somebody point me to proper RFC?

```
--Apple-Mail-DB5AF544-8B2C-45DB-9881-CD5798B20EF8
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="zdjecie 1.JPG"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename*=utf-8''zdj%C4%99cie%201.JPG
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

**decode_header()** form python fails on **filename*=utf-8''zdj%C4%99cie%201.JPG** with UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: Are you sure `name=(...)` is not in the same line as `Content-Type` and `filename*=(...)` is not in the same line as `Content-Disposition`?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Python works fine, I did a mistake by calling decode_header() on filename.